# Getting NoSuchBeanDefinitionException with component-scan xml tag

Tags: java, spring

I am working at my university pet project using Spring and when I try to run my application, I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'moneyService' is defined
```

This is my moneyService bean:

```java
public class MoneyService {
    public void perform(Operation operation) {
        …
    }
}
```

This is how I get this service in my main class:

```java
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("config.xml");
MoneyService service = (MoneyService) context.getBean(“moneyService”);
```

This is my xml configuration file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.example"/>
</beans>
```

MoneyService is located in the package `com.example.services`.

If I add `<bean>` tag in my xml file, it works fine.
However, I know that Spring can handle my classes without directly defining them with the `<bean>` tag.
As far as I understand from the documentation `<component-scan>` tag should solve my issue. But it doesn’t. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

The class `MoneyService` must be annotated with @Service/@Component, otherwise Spring does not know whether it is a bean or not, and whether it needs to be placed in context. Alternatively, in the configuration class (annotated with @Configuration), you must declare the method:

```
@Bean
public MoneyService moneyService() {
    return new MoneyService();
}
```